# Replace line in textfile from a Batch script

Tags: string, batch-file, replace, split

So I have a batch script that does telnet to a switch and runs some commands on it.
I need to change a line every time in a textfile. it's the 5th line with the IP Address. How can I do it?

```
@echo off
set IP=""
:start

set /p IP="Enter IP Adress:"

    echo : IP is set to %IP%
    cd "C:\Program Files\PuTTY\"
    echo : Trying to connect to %IP%
    plink.exe -telnet %IP% < C:\Users\w0w40\Desktop\5ahitn\shruns\commands.txt

for /f "delims=[] tokens=2" %%a in ('ping -4 -n 1 %ComputerName% ^| findstr [') do set NetworkIP=%%a

pause
goto start
```

this is the main batch script, i need to replace COMMANDS.txt which is

```
ITAC
enable
ITAC
copy running-config tftp:
10.51.11.75
```

i need to replace the ip address in the main batch script

Comment: replace with what?

Comment: with NetworkIP variable in the main script

Comment: the IP adress changes everytime so i have to replace it everytime (schoolnetwork)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't replace something within a file with batch. You have to recreate the whole file.

First remove the last line. That's easy, as it's the only line that contains dots:

```
find /v "." commands.txt > commands.tmp
```

then add the new line to the new file:

```
>commands.tmp echo %NetworkIP%
```

and rename it to the original name:

```
move /y commands.tmp commands.txt
```